# Calling object's function in code don't work

Tags: javascript

I've been doing a simple canvas animation using Sprites, everything is fine as long as I call objects functions from browser console, running `coin.draw()` in code and it works but it don't show image attached to this object and when I type `coin.draw()` in browser console it normally draws image, can you explain it to me?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>flipcoin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    coins = new Image();
    coins.src = "coins.png";

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    canvas.height = 500;
    canvas.width = 500;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function Sprite(option) {

        var that = {};

        that.img = option;
        that.width = 44;
        that.height = 40;
        that.context = ctx;
        that.frameIndex = 0;
        that.fps = 60;
        that.time = 0;
        that.start = true;

        that.draw = function() {

            that.context.drawImage(
                that.img,
                0 + that.width * that.frameIndex,
                0,
                that.width,
                that.height,
                0,
                0,
                that.width,
                that.height);

            console.log("works");
        }

        that.update = function() {

            that.time++

                if (that.time > that.fps) {

                    that.time = 0;
                    //that.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    that.draw();
                    that.frameIndex++;

                    if (that.frameIndex == (coins.width / that.width) - 1) {

                        that.frameIndex = 0;

                    }

                }
        }

        that.animate = function() {

            that.update()
            console.log(that.time);
            window.requestAnimationFrame(that.animate());

        }

        return that;
    }


    var coin = new Sprite(coins);
    coin.draw();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is that an exact copy/paste (all of it in one part), or have you put the above code together for the question?

Comment: something might not be ready when you call `draw`. When i tried `window.onload = function(){ coin.draw(); };` it worked fine.

Comment: @Kaddath That's why I asked - click the run button above and it works so that code can't be exactly what they're running.

Comment: You need to use `window.requestAnimationFrame(that.animate);` instead of `window.requestAnimationFrame( that.animate() );`

Comment: @Archer actually it's not working as expected, because the image is supposed to show and there is nothing. Of course the minimal example is wrong here, as it should use an online placeholder image, but the OP was kind enough to provide a full HTML page so that it's easy to test locally with a local image. (i usually skip questions where examples are not verifiable, but this one is the exception i guess)

Comment: @Kaddath The image doesn't show because the path is incorrect (in this context).  Everything runs fine though so I'd call it working as expected (I never expected the image to actually show without an absolute Url).

Comment: @Archer you're right of course, calling a cat a cat ;) i shouldn't actually have made the example verifiable, it's the OP role to do it, but in this case, it was not possible to test to type `coin.draw();` in the console because snippet variables not accessible (as far as i know). But this case was reproductible locally without effort, so..

Comment: @Kaddath also, it's not `window.load` that you should be checking as the image is created dynamically.  That's the problem.  Just posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you have is because the image isn't loaded first time you run the script.  What you can do is make the `Sprite()` function check that and only execute after the image is loaded.

Change this bit...

```
var coin = new Sprite (coins);
coin.draw();
```

to this...

```
var coin = new Sprite (coins);

// coins may not be loaded - we need to check here before we use it
if (coins.complete) {
    coin.draw();
}
else {
    coins.addEventListener("load", function() {
        coin.draw();
    });
}
```

That checks to see if the image is already loaded (which it will be if it's cached) and executes `draw()` if it is.  If it's not it attaches an event handler to the `load` event, so once the image is loaded it will execute `draw()`.

This does not cover the possibility of a load error.  You can add a separate event handler for that, if needed.